# Safe and feasible way to multiplex CAN bus?

Tags: analog, circuit-design, communication, can, analog-switch

Is there a standard method or tool to connect more than one CAN bus to a CAN controller with single CAN interface? Each CAN bus would be directly connected to individual transceivers and then the Tx,Rx of the transceivers would be multiplexed to a single CAN controller? Any suggestions? I was thinking about using Analog switch ICs but most of them are not rated for automotive use and the electrical ratings are not desirable for CAN bus.

Comment: This is only possible for silent nodes. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: You have asked 5 questions which all seem to address the same problem. It seems you're stuck. Maybe the root problem is in the "CAN controller with *single* CAN interface" premise?

Comment: If you need to connect multiple CAN buses to a microcontroller that has only 1 CAN controller, you might want to look for CAN-SPI controllers such as [MCP2515](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP2515-Stand-Alone-CAN-Controller-with-SPI-20001801J.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiyg87F8YnlAhUks4sKHU_3DtwQFjAKegQIAxAG&usg=AOvVaw2X7_4MRydT9umMpikzO-iQ)

Comment: To begin with, do you wish to communicate on two buses simultaneously or either one out of two? In your previous question you mention J1708, which **_does not even seem to be a CAN protocol_**, but something based on RS485. If so, it can't be connected to a CAN transceiver in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use this analog switch for CAN bus signals?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461178/can-i-use-this-analog-switch-for-can-bus-signals)

Comment: The OP has not voted on any question, or marked any question as answered either.

Comment: @dim I can not change the CAN controller. If I had the choice, this problem would not have existed in the first place. J1708 and J1939 are different protocols, I know that part. Imagine a scenario where one manufacturer use a pin for J1708 and other use it for J1939, I need a way to use analog switch or any other switching method to route the signal based on the usage of the pin by manufacturers.

Comment: Also everyone, I am sorry for asking the same question in multiple threads. I am new to this forum and it won't happen again. Thanks